# what is Container Architecture used in MapR distribution?

Tags: hadoop, architecture, hdfs, nfs, mapr

MapR comes  with a new architecture  (Container Architecture) which is different from the HDFS approach .
what is the differnet ? how this stores data ? what are the advantages and disadvantages ?

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fP4HnvZmpZI specifically from 8:35 onwards for an idea on the container architecture.

See also http://answers.mapr.com/questions/301/why-mapr-dfs-is-better-than-hdfs